# Slidebar close on click for anchor

Tags: jquery, menu, anchor

I've added the Slidebar plugin to a site I'm developing.

I have a number of #anchor links on the home page. I would like the Slidebar to close when I click on it and scroll down to the anchor points.

See my JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shmeano66/a5yyqu73/

There are some control classes like .sb-close but it just closes the menu without navigating down to the anchor. I have been looking at the Slidebar API and would like to use .slidebars.close() but I'm unsure how to implement them

HTML

```
<div id="sb-site">
    <a href="#" class="sb-open-left">Press me<a/>



    <div id="about">
        <p>About Section</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sb-slidebar sb-left">

    </div>

    <div class="sb-slidebar sb-left">
      <a href="#about"><p>about</p></a>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$.slidebars = function(options) {

    // ----------------------
    // 001 - Default Settings

    var settings = $.extend({
        siteClose: true, // true or false - Enable closing of Slidebars by clicking on #sb-site.
        scrollLock: false, // true or false - Prevent scrolling of site when a Slidebar is open.
        disableOver: false, // integer or false - Hide Slidebars over a specific width.
        hideControlClasses: false // true or false - Hide controls at same width as disableOver.
    }, options);

    // -----------------------
    // 002 - Feature Detection

    var test = document.createElement('div').style, // Create element to test on.
    supportTransition = false, // Variable for testing transitions.
    supportTransform = false; // variable for testing transforms.

    // Test for CSS Transitions
    if (test.MozTransition === '' || test.WebkitTransition === '' || test.OTransition === '' || test.transition === '') supportTransition = true;

    // Test for CSS Transforms
    if (test.MozTransform === '' || test.WebkitTransform === '' || test.OTransform === '' || test.transform === '') supportTransform = true;

    // -----------------
    // 003 - User Agents

    var ua = navigator.userAgent, // Get user agent string.
    android = false, // Variable for storing android version.
    iOS = false; // Variable for storing iOS version.

    if (/Android/.test(ua)) { // Detect Android in user agent string.
        android = ua.substr(ua.indexOf('Android')+8, 3); // Set version of Android.
    } else if (/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/.test(ua)) { // Detect iOS in user agent string.
        iOS = ua.substr(ua.indexOf('OS ')+3, 3).replace('_', '.'); // Set version of iOS.
    }

    if (android && android < 3 || iOS && iOS < 5) $('html').addClass('sb-static'); // Add helper class for older versions of Android & iOS.

    // -----------
    // 004 - Setup

    // Site container
    var $site = $('#sb-site, .sb-site-container'); // Cache the selector.

    // Left Slidebar    
    if ($('.sb-left').length) { // Check if the left Slidebar exists.
        var $left = $('.sb-left'), // Cache the selector.
        leftActive = false; // Used to check whether the left Slidebar is open or closed.
    }

    // Right Slidebar
    if ($('.sb-right').length) { // Check if the right Slidebar exists.
        var $right = $('.sb-right'), // Cache the selector.
        rightActive = false; // Used to check whether the right Slidebar is open or closed.
    }

    var init = false, // Initialisation variable.
    windowWidth = $(window).width(), // Get width of window.
    $controls = $('.sb-toggle-left, .sb-toggle-right, .sb-open-left, .sb-open-right, .sb-close'), // Cache the control classes.
    $slide = $('.sb-slide'); // Cache users elements to animate.

    // Initailise Slidebars
    function initialise() {
        if (!settings.disableOver || (typeof settings.disableOver === 'number' && settings.disableOver >= windowWidth)) { // False or larger than window size. 
            init = true; // true enabled Slidebars to open.
            $('html').addClass('sb-init'); // Add helper class.
            if (settings.hideControlClasses) $controls.removeClass('sb-hide'); // Remove class just incase Slidebars was originally disabled.
            css(); // Set required inline styles.
        } else if (typeof settings.disableOver === 'number' && settings.disableOver < windowWidth) { // Less than window size.
            init = false; // false stop Slidebars from opening.
            $('html').removeClass('sb-init'); // Remove helper class.
            if (settings.hideControlClasses) $controls.addClass('sb-hide'); // Hide controls
            $site.css('minHeight', ''); // Remove minimum height.
            if (leftActive || rightActive) close(); // Close Slidebars if open.
        }
    }
    initialise();

    // Inline CSS
    function css() {
        // Set minimum height.
        $site.css('minHeight', ''); // Reset minimum height.
        $site.css('minHeight', $('html').height() + 'px'); // Set minimum height of the site to the minimum height of the html.

        // Custom Slidebar widths.
        if ($left && $left.hasClass('sb-width-custom')) $left.css('width', $left.attr('data-sb-width')); // Set user custom width.
        if ($right && $right.hasClass('sb-width-custom')) $right.css('width', $right.attr('data-sb-width')); // Set user custom width.

        // Set off-canvas margins for Slidebars with push and overlay animations.
        if ($left && ($left.hasClass('sb-style-push') || $left.hasClass('sb-style-overlay'))) $left.css('marginLeft', '-' + $left.css('width'));
        if ($right && ($right.hasClass('sb-style-push') || $right.hasClass('sb-style-overlay'))) $right.css('marginRight', '-' + $right.css('width'));

        // Site scroll locking.
        if (settings.scrollLock) $('html').addClass('sb-scroll-lock');
    }

    // Resize Functions
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var resizedWindowWidth = $(window).width(); // Get resized window width.
        if (windowWidth !== resizedWindowWidth) { // Slidebars is running and window was actually resized.
            windowWidth = resizedWindowWidth; // Set the new window width.
            initialise(); // Call initalise to see if Slidebars should still be running.
            if (leftActive) open('left'); // If left Slidebar is open, calling open will ensure it is the correct size.
            if (rightActive) open('right'); // If right Slidebar is open, calling open will ensure it is the correct size.
        }
    });
    // I may include a height check along side a width check here in future.

    // ---------------
    // 005 - Animation

    var animation; // Animation type.

    // Set animation type.
    if (supportTransition && supportTransform) { // Browser supports css transitions and transforms.
        animation = 'translate'; // Translate for browsers that support it.
        if (android && android < 4.4) animation = 'side'; // Android supports both, but can't translate any fixed positions, so use left instead.
    } else {
        animation = 'jQuery'; // Browsers that don't support css transitions and transitions.
    }

    // Animate mixin.
    function animate(object, amount, side) {
        // Choose selectors depending on animation style.
        var selector;

        if (object.hasClass('sb-style-push')) {
            selector = $site.add(object).add($slide); // Push - Animate site, Slidebar and user elements.
        } else if (object.hasClass('sb-style-overlay')) {
            selector = object; // Overlay - Animate Slidebar only.
        } else {
            selector = $site.add($slide); // Reveal - Animate site and user elements.
        }

        // Apply animation
        if (animation === 'translate') {
            selector.css('transform', 'translate(' + amount + ')'); // Apply the animation.

        } else if (animation === 'side') {      
            if (amount[0] === '-') amount = amount.substr(1); // Remove the '-' from the passed amount for side animations.
            if (amount !== '0px') selector.css(side, '0px'); // Add a 0 value so css transition works.
            setTimeout(function() { // Set a timeout to allow the 0 value to be applied above.
                selector.css(side, amount); // Apply the animation.
            }, 1);

        } else if (animation === 'jQuery') {
            if (amount[0] === '-') amount = amount.substr(1); // Remove the '-' from the passed amount for jQuery animations.
            var properties = {};
            properties[side] = amount;
            selector.stop().animate(properties, 400); // Stop any current jQuery animation before starting another.
        }

        // If closed, remove the inline styling on completion of the animation.
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (amount === '0px') {
                selector.removeAttr('style');
                css();
            }
        }, 400);
    }

    // ----------------
    // 006 - Operations

    // Open a Slidebar
    function open(side) {
        // Check to see if opposite Slidebar is open.
        if (side === 'left' && $left && rightActive || side === 'right' && $right && leftActive) { // It's open, close it, then continue.
            close();
            setTimeout(proceed, 400);
        } else { // Its not open, continue.
            proceed();
        }

        // Open
        function proceed() {
            if (init && side === 'left' && $left) { // Slidebars is initiated, left is in use and called to open.
                $('html').addClass('sb-active sb-active-left'); // Add active classes.
                $left.addClass('sb-active');
                animate($left, $left.css('width'), 'left'); // Animation
                setTimeout(function() { leftActive = true; }, 400); // Set active variables.
            } else if (init && side === 'right' && $right) { // Slidebars is initiated, right is in use and called to open.
                $('html').addClass('sb-active sb-active-right'); // Add active classes.
                $right.addClass('sb-active');
                animate($right, '-' + $right.css('width'), 'right'); // Animation
                setTimeout(function() { rightActive = true; }, 400); // Set active variables.
            }
        }
    }

    // Close either Slidebar
    function close(link) {
        if (leftActive || rightActive) { // If a Slidebar is open.
            if (leftActive) {
                animate($left, '0px', 'left'); // Animation
                leftActive = false;
            }
            if (rightActive) {
                animate($right, '0px', 'right'); // Animation
                rightActive = false;
            }

            setTimeout(function() { // Wait for closing animation to finish.
                $('html').removeClass('sb-active sb-active-left sb-active-right'); // Remove active classes.
                if ($left) $left.removeClass('sb-active');
                if ($right) $right.removeClass('sb-active');
                if (typeof link !== 'undefined') window.location = link; // If a link has been passed to the function, go to it.
            }, 400);
        }
    }

    // Toggle either Slidebar
    function toggle(side) {
        if (side === 'left' && $left) { // If left Slidebar is called and in use.
            if (!leftActive) {
                open('left'); // Slidebar is closed, open it.
            } else {
                close(); // Slidebar is open, close it.
            }
        }
        if (side === 'right' && $right) { // If right Slidebar is called and in use.
            if (!rightActive) {
                open('right'); // Slidebar is closed, open it.
            } else {
                close(); // Slidebar is open, close it.
            }
        }
    }

    // ---------
    // 007 - API

    this.slidebars = {
        open: open, // Maps user variable name to the open method.
        close: close, // Maps user variable name to the close method.
        toggle: toggle, // Maps user variable name to the toggle method.
        init: function() { // Returns true or false whether Slidebars are running or not.
            return init; // Returns true or false whether Slidebars are running.
        },
        active: function(side) { // Returns true or false whether Slidebar is open or closed.
            if (side === 'left' && $left) return leftActive;
            if (side === 'right' && $right) return rightActive;
        },
        destroy: function(side) { // Removes the Slidebar from the DOM.
            if (side === 'left' && $left) {
                if (leftActive) close(); // Close if its open.
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $left.remove(); // Remove it.
                    $left = false; // Set variable to false so it cannot be opened again.
                }, 400);
            }
            if (side === 'right' && $right) {
                if (rightActive) close(); // Close if its open.
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $right.remove(); // Remove it.
                    $right = false; // Set variable to false so it cannot be opened again.
                }, 400);
            }
        }
    };

    // ----------------
    // 008 - User Input

    function eventHandler(event, selector) {
        event.stopPropagation(); // Stop event bubbling.
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behaviour.
        if (event.type === 'touchend') selector.off('click'); // If event type was touch, turn off clicks to prevent phantom clicks.
    }

    // Toggle left Slidebar
    $('.sb-toggle-left').on('touchend click', function(event) {
        eventHandler(event, $(this)); // Handle the event.
        toggle('left'); // Toggle the left Slidbar.
    });

    // Toggle right Slidebar
    $('.sb-toggle-right').on('touchend click', function(event) {
        eventHandler(event, $(this)); // Handle the event.
        toggle('right'); // Toggle the right Slidbar.
    });

    // Open left Slidebar
    $('.sb-open-left').on('touchend click', function(event) {
        eventHandler(event, $(this)); // Handle the event.
        open('left'); // Open the left Slidebar.
    });

    // Open right Slidebar
    $('.sb-open-right').on('touchend click', function(event) {
        eventHandler(event, $(this)); // Handle the event.
        open('right'); // Open the right Slidebar.
    });

    // Close Slidebar
    $('.sb-close').on('touchend click', function(event) {
        if ( $(this).is('a') || $(this).children().is('a') ) { // Is a link or contains a link.
            if ( event.type === 'click' ) { // Make sure the user wanted to follow the link.
                event.preventDefault(); // Stop default behaviour.
                var href = ( $(this).is('a') ? $(this).attr('href') : $(this).find('a').attr('href') ); // Get the href.
                close( href ); // Close Slidebar and pass link.
            }
        } else { // Just a normal control class.
            eventHandler(event, $(this)); // Handle the event.
            close(); // Close Slidebar.
        }
    });

    // Close Slidebar via site
    $site.on('touchend click', function(event) {
        if (settings.siteClose && (leftActive || rightActive)) { // If settings permit closing by site and left or right Slidebar is open.
            eventHandler(event, $(this)); // Handle the event.
            close(); // Close it.
        }
    });

}; // End Slidebars function.
```

})

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.slidebars();
    });
  }) (jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have some text in the about page, this will work:

```
$("a[href='#about']").click(function(){
    $.slidebars.close()
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top
    }, 2000);
})
```

For multiple anchors, try this:

(1) Add 'menu' to class, like so:

```
<div class="sb-slidebar sb-left menu" style="background-color: #AAA;">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
```

(2) Change Javascript, like so:

```
$(".menu a").click(function(){
    $.slidebars.close()
    section = $(this).attr('href')
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(section).offset().top
    }, 2000);
})
```

Comment: Thanks Twitch. That worked. What if I have multiple anchors in the menu?